# Can't Access MovieClips' Timelines through stage.getChildAt

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I've simplified my problem down to this self explanatory code. Why doesn't each Movie Clip on the stage go to frame two? The error occurs on line six.

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,update);
function update(e:Event)
{
    for (var i:int=0; i<stage.numChildren; i++)
    {
        stage.getChildAt(i).gotoAndPlay(2);//error here
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `getChildAt` method returns an instance of `DisplayObject` (see [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#getChildAt())), but you're trying to call a method on the instance which is a member of the `MovieClip` class. You need to cast the instance returned to the correct type:

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,update);
function update(e:Event)
{
    for (var i:int=0; i<stage.numChildren; i++)
    {
        MovieClip(stage.getChildAt(i)).gotoAndPlay(2); // cast instance to MovieClip
    }
}
```